# Maps in salesforce

Tags: apex

I have one requirement in that we have to put the two field values as a key for that map and another field as variable

ex:

```
lcode
mcode
rnumber

lcode+mcode as akey
rnumber as value
```

how to do this

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: When posting a question please provide more details. Are you doing this in Apex? Are you doing this in Javascript inside VF or Lightning Components? Also as Homer answered a simple Google search on "Collections in Apex Salesforce" will provide you the documentation link to how to use Sets, Lists, and Maps.

Answer (score 1):

Everything you need to know about Maps is found here:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_collections_maps.htm